# Error installing kivy python on macbook m1

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to install KIVY on macbook, I had the most recent version of python 3.11, I already deleted it and installed 3.8, and it keeps giving me the same error when installing:

```
pip install kivy --user
```

ERROR CMD:

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for kivy
Failed to build kivy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for kivy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Does this error have a solution? I've been looking for information on the internet for two days but everything I see I do and it's still the same, nothing.

Or is there another easier-to-install library that doesn't cause so much trouble and is cross-platform? For ios app with python.

Answer (score 0):

Kivy has issues with Python version 3.11. Try to downgrade to a lower version, like 3.10. That should work!